# Fetch.Eager not working for my code

Tags: hibernate

I have this code

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "component_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Component component;
```

in a class called ServerComponent. So when serverComponent object is loaded it's property component is also supposed to be loaded. But instead null value is coming i.e. serverComponent.getComponent()=null.

All this is happening during running test case which means no actual data entry is happening in database but every object/instance and its properties are being retained in hibernate memory only. 
Rest of the properties are getting loaded fine.

I am new to hibernate. Please help!!!

Comment: If getCompoment() is null, then it has nothing to do with lazy or eager, since getComponent() would cause a lazily-loaded member to be fetched.  There's something else wrong.  Have you saved the objects correctly?

Comment: The object is in hibernate memory like other members. I am not persisting it in database. When i am fetching component using another specific call i.e. xxxService.getComponent(id), I am able to get it. But unable to get it as a part of ServerComponent bean

Comment: If it's not persisted to at least an in-memory database, how would Hibernate be involved?  Perhaps you should post a little code: how do you populate "hibernate memory", and how do you load the ServerComponent object?